# Remove or hide notification bar in android

Tags: android, notifications

i am developing an application, when the app is open there may be any missed call the notification is displayed,how i hide or remove the notification bar & is there any way to implement it.
i have put all codes like below in my application,

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

and

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

but i open an activity file using broadcast receiver, then the notification is seen when missed call or message arrives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the exact same problem as yours, but I hade it for both incoming and outgoing calls. I found the solution for the incoming calls/ missed calls but not yet for the outgoing calls.

What you are going to do is the following: 
 1.Create a BroadCastReceiver Class to listen to incoming calls with the highest priority:

a.In the Manifest.xml add:

```
    <receiver android:name=".MyPhoneBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="99999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

b.Then the Class

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {

        String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);          
        final String incomingNumber = extras.getString("incoming_number");

        Handler callActionHandler = new Handler();

        Runnable runRingingActivity = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 //Notice the intent, cos u will add intent filter for your class(CustomCallsReceiver)
                Intent intentPhoneCall = new Intent("android.intent.action.ANSWER");
                intentPhoneCall.putExtra("INCOMING_NUM", incomingNumber);
                intentPhoneCall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intentPhoneCall);
            }
        };
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            //increase the delay amount if problem occur something like -the screen didn't show up- that's the key about this method(the delay).
            callActionHandler.postDelayed(runRingingActivity, 100);    
        }
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            callActionHandler.removeCallbacks(runRingingActivity);
        }

    }
}
```

2.a.In the Manifest.xml file add this intent filter for the class you will use as a custome call receiver.

```
    <activity android:name="CustomCallsReceiver" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ANSWER" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>    
    </activity>
```

2.b.The CustomeCallsReceiver Class:

```
public class CustomCallsReceiver extends Activity {

private String TAG = "CustomCallsReceiver";
String incomingNumber, caller;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custome_calls_receiver);

    TextView number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
    number.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    incomingNumber = getIntent().getExtras().getString("INCOMING_NUM");
    caller = getCallerName(incomingNumber);

    if (caller != null) {
        number.setText(caller + "\n" + incomingNumber);  }  }
```

3.And finally of course don't forget to add the Theme for not title or notification bar at the Manifest.XML file

```
    <application
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

Comment: I've tried the same technique with the outgoing calls (when calling) but the thing is when decreasing the delay which is the key in making all this happens (my screen shows and no notification) my calling screen doesn't appear and the default dialer for android is shown.  

If you found a way of doing it, please share . thanks

Comment: i also find the solution for incomming calls only but i have no solution for the outgoing call, but my idea is make the outgoing call has emergency call then it not allow the user to go to the homescreen if you have any idea about make a emergency call? i accept your above answer thanks for your reply...\

Comment: I've tried a very dirty solution and I have no choice but to go with it until I find a better one, the thing is I call "this.finish" for the calling activity after the call ends then I call an activity which is my homescreen that subsequently calls my calling activity from the first place, this way I refresh the screen and the bar disappear ..... As I told you It's like the worst thing I've ever come up with.
and please if you accept my previous answer can you vote me Up :D

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code:

```
public class FullScreen
    extends android.app.Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not working i am asking about app is already in running state and in between time any missed call arrives there be a notification bar in above i set all above code already...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the theme in Android manifest .xml.. .

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Hope this will help you..

if you set this as application theme it will give effect all the pages of  your app..

```
   <application
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         >
```

Comment: for me its working.. i have checked it... see the code in edit for how to set it . if user want to see any notifications.. he have to close or minimize your application. then only he can able to see...